# UNITY 2017 PROBLEMS WITH SDK MANAGER

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, apk, android-sdk-manager

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>   "C:...\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v
>   -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/...\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_
>   --extra-packages com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.games.bridge:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4

I have this error on Unity and i have no idea why this is happening. I have downloaded SDK MANAGER 2017 and SDK MANAGER 25.0.2 so please help me, i have no what is going on here, NONE OF THESE VERSIONS WORKED, i'm new to unity, i have never used it before so, yep. Help :c

Comment: You may be missing some components. Edit your question with the contents of `sdkmanager --list` which can be run from the command line (you'll need to cd to the sdk directory first) https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#list_installed_and_available_packages

Comment: I have everything i need to build an APK but isn't working